# How come my box does not disappear when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a box which contains links inside it. I do not understand why it does not disappear when page has loaded. I wanted to appear when a button onclick = "ore();" is clicked.

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById("hid").style.display = "none";
  function ore(){
    document.getElementById("hid").style.diplay = "block";
  }
</script>
<div class= "borl" id = "hid" style = "position: absolute; text-align: center; width: auto; height: auto; left: 46%; top: 30%;">
  <a href = "#">Notifications</a><br>
  <a href = "#">Logout</a><br>
  <a href = "#">Report</a><br />
  <a href = "#">Bizzy Emails</a><br>
  <a href = "#">Help and Support</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your script running before the page is loaded?

Comment: A script can't act on an element that hasn't been rendered yet.

Comment: I changed the script location but when I press the button the box does not show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add your script after html

```html
<div class="borl" id="hid" style="position: absolute; text-align: center; width: auto; height: auto; left: 46%; top: 30%;">
  <a href="#">Notifications</a><br>
  <a href="#">Logout</a><br>
  <a href="#">Report</a><br />
  <a href="#">Bizzy Emails</a><br>
  <a href="#">Help and Support</a>
</div>
<button onclick="ore()">show</button>
<script>
  document.getElementById('hid').style.display = "none";
  function ore(){
    document.getElementById('hid').style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't _have_ to, but that's one possible solution.

Comment: But when I press the button that contains onclick = "ore();", the box does not show up

Comment: please run code snippet and check, when you click on show button it will display your menu

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky check in your code you mistake in display spelling

Comment: Thank you, yes that was the mistake.